# Convert SQL with Inner AND Outer Join to L2S

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I need to convert the below Sproc to a Linq query.  At the very bottom is what I have so far.  For reference the fields behind the "splat"(*not my sproc*) are

`ImmunizationID int, HAReviewID int, ImmunizationMaintID int, ImmunizationOther varchar(50), ImmunizationDate smalldatetime, ImmunizationReasonID int`

The first two are PK and FK, respectively.  The other two `int`s are linke to the Maint Table where there description is stored.  That is what I am stuck on, the `INNER JOIN` AND the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Thanks,

```
SELECT tblHAReviewImmunizations.*, 
       tblMaintItem.ItemDescription, 
       tblMaintItem2.ItemDescription as Reason
FROM 
       dbo.tblHAReviewImmunizations 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblMaintItem 
            ON dbo.tblHAReviewImmunizations.ImmunizationMaintID =
                dbo.tblMaintItem.ItemID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblMaintItem as tblMaintItem2 
            ON dbo.tblHAReviewImmunizations.ImmunizationReasonID =
                tblMaintItem2.ItemID 
WHERE
       HAReviewID = @haReviewID
```

---

My attempt so far -->

```
public static DataTable GetImmunizations(int haReviewID)
{
    using (var context = McpDataContext.Create())
    {
        var currentImmunizations =
            from haReviewImmunization in context.tblHAReviewImmunizations
            where haReviewImmunization.HAReviewID == haReviewID
            join maintItem in context.tblMaintItems
                on haReviewImmunization.ImmunizationReasonID 
                equals maintItem.ItemID into g
            from maintItem in g.DefaultIfEmpty() 
            let Immunization = GetImmunizationNameByID(
                haReviewImmunization.ImmunizationMaintID)
            select new
            {
                haReviewImmunization.ImmunizationDate,
                haReviewImmunization.ImmunizationOther,
                Immunization,
                Reason = maintItem == null ? " " : maintItem.ItemDescription
            };

        return currentImmunizations.CopyLinqToDataTable();
    }
}

private static string GetImmunizationNameByID(int? immunizationID)
{
    using (var context = McpDataContext.Create())
    {
        var domainName =
            from maintItem in context.tblMaintItems
            where maintItem.ItemID == immunizationID
            select maintItem.ItemDescription;

        return domainName.SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static DataTable GetImmunizations(int haReviewID)
{
    using (var context = McpDataContext.Create())
    {
        var currentImmunizations =
            from haReviewImmunization in context.tblHAReviewImmunizations
            where haReviewImmunization.HAReviewID == haReviewID

            join maintItem in context.tblMaintItems
            on haReviewImmunization.ImmunizationMaintID 
            equals maintItem.ItemID

            join maintItem2 in context.tblMaintItems
            on haReviewImmunization.ImmunizationReasonID 
            equals maintItem2.ItemID into g
            from maintItem3 in g.DefaultIfEmpty()

            select new
            {
                haReviewImmunization.ImmunizationDate,
                haReviewImmunization.ImmunizationOther,
                maintItem.ItemDescription,
                Reason = maintItem3 == null ? " " : maintItem3.ItemDescription
            };

        return currentImmunizations.CopyLinqToDataTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems so simple when it is staring me in the face!

Comment: No worries, that's a great picture btw!

Comment: A follow up question; is this part --> `into g
            from maintItem3 in g.DefaultIfEmpty()` what makes the second join a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?